# permissions.request for window.open

Tags: javascript, browser, permissions

How do I make a request to ask for permission to open pop-up windows?

What parameters do I put in permissions.request() to request permission to open the pop-ups?[image]

Comment: You can't. That's the point of the browser blocking annoying popups. I'd suggest looking in to creating modals within your UI instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing this. The only thing you can do is asking your users to go edit the settings in their brower or, as Rory said by commenting your post, create your own within your website.